# How can I use a class that has functional dependencies to define another class's constraint?

Tags: haskell

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}

class Fractional f => Point3D p f | p -> f where
    x :: p -> f
    y :: p -> f
    z :: p -> f

class (Fractional fr, Point3D p fr, Foldable f) => HasPoints3D ps p f where
    points :: ps -> f p
```

I made `Point3D` class to cover diverse implementations of 3D Point. And I made `HasPoints3D` class to cover all things that have some points. The second type variable `f` in `Point3D` definition is determined by the first type variable `p`. So, I think this definition of `HasPoints3D` have no problem, because `fr` is can determined by `p`.

I know that it may cause [typechecker loop](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/6.10.2/docs/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html). So, I added `{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}`. But it is not working, it says `Not in scope: type variable ‘fr’`. Is there another haskell extension to make this work? Or haskell just can't deal with this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I tend to avoid functional dependencies, preferring to use type families instead when possible. I think it's often simpler, and avoids issues like this one.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class Fractional (F p) => Point3D p where
    type F p
    x :: p -> F p
    y :: p -> F p
    z :: p -> F p

class (Fractional (F p), Point3D p, Foldable f) => HasPoints3D ps p f where
    points :: ps -> f p
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with chi that `Points3D` should probably not be a multi-parameter class in the first place. But if you can't do anything about that, you can still just use an associated type family in `HasPoints3D`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ..., TypeFamilies, FlexibleContexts #-}

import Data.Kind (Type)

class ( Fractional (DirectionalComponent ps p f)
      , Point3D p (DirectionalComponent ps p f)
      , Foldable f ) => HasPoints3D ps p f where
   type DirectionalComponent ps p f :: Type
   points :: ps -> f p
```

BTW, I find the `Point3D` abstraction highly dubious. Why do you need a typeclass for this? This sounds like it behaves like just one concrete type

```
data V3 s = V3 {x,y,z :: !s}
```

What would likely make much more sense to **not** require specifically three dimensions with any particular coordinate axes, but instead be abstract over the [vector space](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space) you're working in.

Similarly, why do you need the `HasPoints3D` class? Why not just use `f p` as it is, with suitable constraints on `f` and `p` separatly, as needed?

Suggest reading: [Rules of thumb for when to use a type class](https://harry.garrood.me/blog/down-with-show-part-1/).